# passing an argument to a custom save() method

Tags: python, django, django-models

How do I pass an argument to my custom save method, preserving  proper `*args`, `**kwargs` for passing to te super method? I was trying something like:

```
form.save(my_value)
```

and

```
def save(self, my_value=None, *args, **kwargs):

   super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

   print my_value
```

But this doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I found this example (see the last message, for passing 'reorder'):
http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/b285698ea3cabfc9/6ce8a4517875cb40?lnk=raot

This is essentially what I am trying to do, but `my_value` is said to be an unexpected argument for some reason.

Comment: You're unrolling the arguments in the call to save!

Comment: Defined method `save(self, my_value=None, *args, **kwargs)` expects keyword argument: `save(my_value=some_value)` (check this question about [positional and keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450656/positional-argument-v-s-keyword-argument/57819001#57819001))

Answer (score 26):

Keyword arguments must follow the positional arguments.  Try this instead:

```
def save(self, my_value, *args, **kwargs):
    ....
```

or:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    my_value = kwargs.pop('my_value', None)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do the trick - python says it's a syntax error

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following.

Override the save method as:

```
def save(self, my_val, *args, **kwargs):
    print my_val
    # do_something here
    return super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

On calling the save method as:

```
MyModel.save(my_val="fooooo")
```

this will print `my_val` and save it.

Answer (score 3):

The existing answers are incomplete.

The problem with `Model.save` is that there are multiple ways to get to it, most notably through `Model.objects.create()`. A queryset `create()` call *will not* pass additional arguments to `Model.save` and your code might not behave as expected.

You can easily see the source code for `create()` and other methods (get_or_create, update_or_create) here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2.7/django/db/models/query.py#L415

The `bulk_create` method of QuerySet does not call `save` *at all*. Which means any custom logic will be entirely ignored.

Because of these risks I would consider the premise of the question an anti-pattern to be avoided. Rather than overloading the built in save method, create an entirely different (factory) method to encompass your special behavior e.g. `mymodel.special_save()`.