# Passing parameters from partial form to model during save Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model with many fields, for which I am creating two partial forms

```
#model
class Line_Settings(models.Model):
....
    line = models.ForeignKey(Line)
    All = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Busy = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    MOH = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    PLAR = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
....

    def save(self, commit = True, *args, **kwargs):
       ....
#Partial model form1
class General(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Line_Settings
        fields = ('MOH','PLAR')
#Partial model form2        
class Common(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Line_Settings
        fields = ('All','Busy')
```

I have overwritten the save for the Line_Settings model to do additional logic.

I need to be able to pass some parameters to the overwritten save method to use in my logic.

In my views I fill up the two partials forms with post data and can call save.

```
call_forwards = Common(request.POST, instance=line_settings)
general = General(request.POST, instance=line_settings)
```

I need to pass a parameter to the save like so:

```
call_forwards.save(parameter="value")
general.save(parameter="value")
```

I have referred to [passing an argument to a custom save() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535435/passing-an-argument-to-a-custom-save-method)

I can get access to the parameter if I overwrite the save on my partial form.

```
# overwritten save of partial form
def save(self, parameter, commit=True):
     print("In save overwrite Partial form Common "+str(parameter))
     #how Can I pass this parameter to the model save overwirite?
     super(Common, self).save(commit)
```

From the partial form, how do I make the parameter reach my original model(Line_Settings) save overwrite?

Can this be done?
Thanks in advance for reading!!

Comment: Unfortunately, ModelForm provides no way to pass parameters to the instance save() method, so you'd have to override and reimplement the form save method, or call it with commit=False and save it manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by defining a parameter in my original models `__init__` method

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.parameter= None
    super(Line_Settings, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then in the partial form, I could access this parameter and set it to value passed during save

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
     self.instance.parameter = kwargs.pop('parameter', None)
     super(Common, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In my view I called the save as :

```
common = Common(request.POST, instance=line_settings)
common.save(parameter="something")
```