# How to pass arguments to custom save method of django model?

Tags: django, model, save

This should be easy and there is another question on SO that addresses the issue ( [passing an argument to a custom save() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535435/passing-an-argument-to-a-custom-save-method) ) but that solution isn't working for me. In my view I have `form.save('test string')` and in the corresponding model I have

```
def save(self, test, *args, **kwargs):
    x = test
    ...
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But I keep getting `save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'test'` I have tried `form.save(test='test string')` but that results in `save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'test'`. Finally, I changed the method signature to `def save(self, *args, **kwargs)` and then in the view tried `form.save({'test': 'test string'})` there is no error but nothing appears in the kwargs.

I'm using django 1.10 if that matters. Please help and thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python Your problem is about the comprehension of *args and **kwargs

Comment: You seem to be confused between the form and the model; you're modifying the model save method, but you're calling the form save. You may need to explain in more detail what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I was wondering about that but when I call form.save() I do reach the save() method on the model (assuming I don't worry about passing arguments). I'm trying to populate some fields in the modelform based upon fields from another form in the same template that gets submitted along with the modelform.

Comment: hack, assign in self. like `self.x=test` then you can get `x` in `save` method.